# Where could I get qt default plastique qss file?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtstylesheets, qstylesheet

I wanted to copy QComboBox stylesheet but I couldn't find qss file for plastique style.

Comment: Qt widget styles are plugin-based, so there is no qss file to find. User-defined stylesheets are applied on top of the styling that is done by the style plugin.

Comment: Is there any any documentation or source code with full plastique style somewhere?

Comment: Of course there's source code, but I doubt whether you'll find any of it very useful. Perhaps you should edit your question and explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to use plastique style-sheet on a widget whose default stylesheet is overridden.

Comment: There are no default stylesheets for any of the widgets in Qt. All the styling is done programmatically by the style plugins.

Comment: I think what he is looking to do is to have a qss stylesheet for a few of the plastique elements.  For example... it would be nice to have the same rounded buttons and rounded tab widgets from the plastique style, but in qss style format, so he can override his current style.  He probably doesn't need the entire plastique style.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt 5, the QPlastiqueStyle and its friends have been removed. However they have been put in their own module so you can clone it from the [qtstyleplugins repository](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtstyleplugins.git/) to read its code.

Nothing forbids you from using them though if you need.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cloned the repository but I couldn't get any style code. On which file could I get it?

Comment: Probably `src/plugins/styles/plastique/qplastiquestyle.cpp`.

Comment: There is no qt style in there.

Comment: Right from the repository: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtstyleplugins.git/tree/src/plugins/styles/plastique/qplastiquestyle.cpp

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not there.

Comment: That's the source of the QPlastiqueStyle. If that's not what you want then what are you looking for exactly ?

Comment: Just qss stylesheet of it. I want to use it on QGIS PyQt application.

Comment: There's no stylesheet to find in this case. QPlastiqueStyle is a full style.